How can I delete my account
I request for a deletion of my phantom wallet because I no longer need it

Could you provide more context. Deleting the app/extension should resolve this.

Closing accounts on Solana involves transferring all the SOL in them so that they are no longer rent exempt.

There are websites where you can close all of your accounts and claim your rent back like: https://soldustvacuum.app/ or https://sol-incinerator.com/
